# How to i solve the MissingMethodException when using FSharp.Data.Json.JsonValue.Parse

Tags: f#, f#-data, missingmethodexception

Trying to parse a simple json string with the FSharp.Data.Json library and am faced with the following error. I am using F# 2.0 interactive. Any thoughts on how to go about solving the error

> JsonValue.Parse(@"{""id"": ""117sds""}");;
>   System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: '!!0 Microsoft.FSharp.Collections.SeqModule.ExactlyOne(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<!!0>)'.
>
>      at FSharp.Data.Json.JsonParser..ctor(String jsonText, FSharpOption`1 culture)
>      at FSharp.Data.Json.JsonValue.Parse(String text, FSharpOption`1 culture) in C:\Tomas\Projects\FSharp.Data\src\Library\Json.fs:line 215
>      at .$FSI_0063.main@()

Comment: `Seq.ExactlyOne` is in the `Seq` module, which is in `FSharp.Core.dll`.  Have you checked if F# is correctly installed where you are running this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Jack pointed out, the F# Data library really only works with F# 3.0. If you can update the F# version, it will work and you'll get other benefits (like type providers).

If you cannot upgrade then you can probably just copy the file with JSON parser and runtime to your project and change a few things to support F# 2.0 (the licence allows that). The file you need is [Json.fs](https://github.com/fsharp/FSharp.Data/tree/master/src/Library).

I don't think we'd want to support 2.0 version (so far), but if the fix is easy, submit a pull request with the change and we can merge that to make this easier for others.

Comment: The MSDN page seems to imply that `ExactlyOne` is supported in F# 2.0 ( F# Core Library Versions Supported in: 2.0, 4.0, Portable).  Is this a documentation bug?

Comment: @JohnPalmer The documentation is talking about .NET Framework versions; it probably could be a bit clearer though. You can tell the `Seq.exactlyOne` function is only supported in F# 3.0 because at the top of the page, `Visual Studio 2012` is only text; if the method was supported in other versions, it'd be a link which'd allow you to navigate to the docs from other versions (e.g., `Visual Studio 2010`).

Answer (score 4):

[`Seq.exactlyOne`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh289759.aspx) is a method which is only available in F# 3.0. Unfortunately, there's not going to be an easy way to use the FSharp.Data library from within F# 2.0.

Answer (score 0):

As of version 1.1.6, the runtime components (Json parser, Csv parser and Http utilities) no longer use any method not present in FSharp.Core 4.0.0.0 (the F# 2.0 version), so you'll be able to use FSharp.Data with F# 2.0 if you don't use the type providers